Add subdomain that can be accessed locally with nginx
I have the nginx.conf file:
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  website.test;
        location / {
             proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        }
}
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  server.website.test;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1337;
        }
}

And an edited hosts file:
127.0.0.1 website.test
127.0.0.1 server.website.test

Why does the url "http://website.test" give 502 error, but "http:website.test:3000" does work?
How do I change the config so that I don't need to supply a port in the URL?
I have looked at nginx docs and similar SO post to no avail. I've noticed that if I instead supply my devices IPv4 address (192.168.xxx.yyy) to "proxy_pass" it does work. But thats not what I am looking for. I would like this to work regardless of whether my device is connected to a network or not.

The 502 should also write some info into your error log file (might be at /var/log/nginx/error.log).
If the provided is your full config, you are likely missing some headers for the reverse proxy to act like one.
The default set of headers I set for reverse-proxy'ing are:
add_header          X-Upstream $upstream_addr;
proxy_http_version  1.1;
proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

Many apps do work if you only provide Host and X-Real-IP, but I personally hat much luck with combing them to this template I include on proxy configs. Just add them inside your location {}, and try it...
